# Accessing google driver from google colab - Failure("Unexpected error response:

Tags: python, drive, google-colaboratory

I am following this instructions to get access to google drive through google colab:[gdrive_colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1srw_HFWQ2SMgmWIawucXfusGzrj1_U0q#scrollTo=5Jk9jZm8mhFX)

First two cells work just fine, but the following cell:

```
# Generate creds for the Drive FUSE library.
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
# Work around misordering of STREAM and STDIN in Jupyter.
# https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3159
prompt = !google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass(prompt[0] + '\n\nEnter verification code: ')
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

generates the following error:

```
Please, open the following URL in a web browser: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&response_type=code&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force
Please enter the verification code: Cannot retrieve auth tokens.
Failure("Unexpected error response: {\n  \"error\" : \"invalid_grant\",\n  \"error_description\" : \"Malformed auth code.\"\n}")
Please, open the following URL in a web browser: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&response_type=code&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force

Enter verification code: ··········
```

Any thoughts how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a mistake for new version. Here is a [solution](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/243)